# Loop through three worksheets and delete table data in each sheet

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I've put together the below function to loop through three specific worksheets in a workbook and delete the table contents for tables in each worksheet.

I get

> 'Runtime Error 9, subscript out of range'

When I debug

```vb
For Each tbl In Sheets(Sht).ListObjects
```

is highlighted.

```vb
Sub ClearTableData()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim Sht As Variant
    
    'Loop through each sheet and table in the workbook
    For Each Sht In Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")
        For Each tbl In Sheets(Sht).ListObjects
            'Delete table rows
            tbl.DataBodyRange.Delete
        Next tbl
    Next Sht
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know where the error occurs

Comment: Hi Andreas, when I look at the debug, the row 'For Each tbl In Sheets(Sht).ListObjects' is what's highlighted in yellow.

Comment: Subscript Error 9 means it doesn't exist.  Do you have three sheets with those names?  Not the codenames, but the sheet names on the tabs?

Comment: Hi Darrell, yes those three sheet names do exist. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the spelling of the tabs in question and noticed someone had put a space at the end of 'Sheet2' hence it not being recognised. Thanks for the idea Darrell.